# How to remove largest number in binary search tree?

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I know how to build a binary tree, but I need a method
public void `delMax()` which removes the largest number of the tree. So that means I have to remove the value which is in the last position on the right side.

A recursive method would make sense, but how exactly can I set the right node to the next position to check if the `next is != null`?

```
public class Node
{
    int data;
    Node left;
    Node right;
}

public class BinarySearchTree {
    private Node root = null;
}


    public void delMax()
{
root = delMaxR(root);
}
private static Node delMaxR(Node p)
{
if (p == null)
return null;
if (p.right == null)
p
= p.left;
else
p.right = delMaxR(p.right);
return p;
}
}
```

Comment: I can´t provide any code as long as i don´t have a suggestion how to start. I tried for 2 hours already.

Comment: Without knowing the implementation of the binary tree, we cannot help you. How would you define an operation on a data structure without knowing the data structure? We need at least an interface. And showing (some of) your failed attempt can help us explain what you do not understand.

Comment: Just traverse to the far right ( e.g. node = node.right ) until you hit a null. Then mark the prev node as null ?

Comment: I added the class Node. The binary tree is just a common tree.

Comment: No need for recursion, just loop until `node.right == null` keeping track of the previous node, then set `prev.right = null`. Of course there's the special case where `root` is the max, but I'm sure you can figure that out :)

Comment: @d.j.brown and there is the case where the rightmost node has a left child. If OP has all common operations implemented, then looping to the rightmost node and deleting this node should do the trick.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and good job editing your question! The first question is always a big hurdle. Please don't be discouraged. (I properly indented your code for you. You can do it yourself next time.)

Comment: @Turing85 true!

Comment: I think this should work. Thanks to d.j.brown and Turing85

Comment: @AlpinWhite I suggest fixing the indentation on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first check: What's the structure of a binary searchtree.

It's a tree where each nodes left child is smaller than the node itself. 
So by knowing that, the right child of each node has to be larger.

So that way it's quite easy to remove the largest entry by accessing each right child of nodes you traverse. When there are no more right-childs, you have to check, if there's a left child. If there's a left child, you need to re-attach it to the right child of the parent of the node you delete.

Here some pseudo-code to show you the direction:

```
prevNode = root;
traverser = root;
while(traverser.right != null){
  prevNode = traverser;
  traverser = traverser.right;
}

if(traverser.left != null) {
  prevNode.right = traverser.left;
}else {
  prevNode.right = null;
}
```